# Is there a way to specify hostname in laravel octane

Tags: laravel, octane

When i start octane it always use this host `http ://127.0.0.1:8000` , which is usable in local development, but in production environnement i use domain name instead of localhost
Is there a way to change the hostname like `http ://domain.com:8000` when we start octane.

**Update:**
I'm using apache

**Update:**
I switched to Nginx so, it works better than apache. But if someone managed to resolve this in Apache feel welcome to leave your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need Nginx or Apache. It's already on [Octane Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/octane#serving-your-application-via-nginx).

In the Nginx configuration example below file, Nginx will serve the site's static assets and proxy requests to the Octane server that is running on port 8000:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80; // or 8000
    listen [::]:80; // or 8000
    server_name domain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /your/octane_path/public;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location /index.php {
        try_files /not_exists @octane;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @octane;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location @octane {
        set $suffix "";

        if ($uri = /index.php) {
            set $suffix ?$query_string;
        }

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000$suffix;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm aware of that but i'm using apache and i cannot either use my own domain or even https instead of http (OCTANE_HTTPS is set to true)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hostname by passing the option `--host=your-host` to the octane command.